# Call function from shared library in GCC with inline assembler

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, call, shared

I've created shared library (will be used like plugin). There are a lot of functions like a

```
extern "C" long __attribute__ ((__cdecl__)) SumAgrs(long X, long Y, long Z, long *Out)
{
    *Out = X + Y + Z;
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to call functions from this library in C++(GCC, Linux), but not in compile time. When I use inline assembler, the "push" instruction corrupt local variables, and i have no idea how to fix it.

```
typedef int (*FARPROC)();

void *dl_handle = dlopen("plugin.so", RTLD_LAZY);
FARPROC proc = (FARPROC)dlsym(dl_handle, "SumAgrs");

long result;

asm("leal %0, %%eax\n\r" \
    "pushl %%eax" : : "m" (result));
asm("pushl $10");
asm("pushl $15");
asm("pushl $20");
asm("call *%0" : : "m" (proc));
```

Result binary file contains something like **call *24(%esp)**. So my **pushl** change **%esp** and **call** cause segmentation fault. But how to avoid this behavior?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at libffi: "A Portable Foreign Function Interface Library"

"The libffi library provides a portable, high level programming interface to various calling conventions. This allows a programmer to call any function specified by a call interface description at run-time."

http://sourceware.org/libffi/

Answer (score 0):

You needn't assembler to call functions, actually:

```
extern "C" 
{
    typedef long __attribute__ ((__cdecl__)) (*Proc)(long X, long Y, long Z, long *Out);
}

void *dl_handle = dlopen("plugin.so", RTLD_LAZY);
Proc proc = (Proc)dlsym(dl_handle, "SumAgrs");

proc(...); // call
```

Note, that either you call functions with c-code, or with ASM inline, your code for call generated in *compile* time. You cannot pass `string` variable to `asm`, because code for your `asm` inline should be generated during program compilation. That means you cannot do

```
std::string asm_code;
std:: cin >> asm_code;
asm(asm_code);
```

Comment: Functions will be called from script and parameters are stored in array. So the compile time "call" isn't solution.

Comment: no no, with the ASM inline, the code will be generated in run-time. For example (pseudocode): **foreach (params) { push parm; } call func;**

Comment: @user1173308, You cannot act like that! You never sure, that `foreach(params)` does not use stack pointer inside it, and of course,  it does not assume you will change it by hands! **Do not write such code**